# Why getScript does not work from an external script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am trying to get the google recaptcha script to get loaded with

```
$.getScript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit");
```

If I put it into the `<script>` tags and inline the webpage, it loades the captcha correctly, while If I include the getScript, inside an external `.js` file still hosted on the same domain the javascript from recaptcha is not loaded. Is this a problem with the script itself or with `getScript`?

Comment: Do you get any errors while doing this? Probably there might be some issues with the link, or that the link it's outside your domain origin.

Comment: Has jQuery loaded before you load the external version of the script? Use developer tools in your browser (F12) to check the console log for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you're calling is rendered when the 'onload' event fires.

```
(function() {
  if (!window['___grecaptcha_cfg']) { 
    window['___grecaptcha_cfg'] = {}; 
  };
  if (!window['___grecaptcha_cfg']['render']) {


    // If the render time isn't set, set it to (window) onload //

    window['___grecaptcha_cfg']['render'] = 'onload';      


  };
  window['__google_recaptcha_client'] = true;
  var po = document.createElement('script'); 
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  po.async = true;po.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20150826120751/recaptcha__en.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

I'm not familiar with the google Captcha specs, but I think this can work.  You just need to find the script url that executes in context.  Hint: the URL probably won't say 'onload=onloadCallback' in it.

Comment: That script can't be loaded directly because there is no way to know directly when it finished to load because it load external resources itself